# remove duplicates based on existing column

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the below CSV file:

```
"Path","destination","isCopied"
"E:\DCMCache\file1","V:\dcmcache"
"E:\DCMCache\file2","V:\dcmcache","1"
"E:\DCMCache\file1","V:\dcmcache","1"
"E:\DCMCache\file3","V:\dcmcache","1"
"E:\DCMCache\file4","V:\dcmcache","1"
```

I need to remove the duplicates but only if the `isCopied` is null.

I've tried to use:

```
Import-CSV $InputFile | Group-Object Path | foreach-object { $_.group | sort-object Path | select -last 1 } |Export-Csv $InputFile-completed.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

But it only works if the dupe I want removed is listed first. Wondering what I'm missing (newbie programmer here) :)

Thanks!

Comment: I feel that there might be more conditions to consider that you don't have in your test data. So the first line needs to be removed because it already has a matching `path` or `path` and `destination`. If there is a duplicate we only keep the one with copies? What if there is more than two duplicates? Which one prevails or is there only ever two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have this so far.

```powershell
Import-Csv $InputFile | Group-Object Path | ForEach-Object{
    If($_.Count -gt 1){
        $_.Group | Where-Object{$_.isCopied}
    } Else {
        $_.Group
    }
} | Export-Csv $InputFile-completed.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Take your logic for Grouping and then check each `count`. If the count is greater than 1 we only allow entries that have an `isCopied` value. So you should be able to output this to file easily.

If something is wrong with this logic you might need to include a better source file with more conditions. As it stands this satisfies the basic requirement.

If you needed to be more specific with the duplicated that `where` clause is where you would make changes.

In the event there are more than two copies you could always add to that `where-object` with a `Sort-Object isCopied -Desc | Select-Object -First 1`